# How Could I be sure bean validation is working?

Tags: java

I got this simple bean:

```
public class Person {
   @Min(value=18,message="Wrong!")
   private int age;

   public int getAge() {
     return age;
   }

   public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
   }
}
```

I'm going to test the validation on `age`, I used that in a servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Person p=new Person();
    p.setAge(7);
    response.getWriter().print(p.getAge());
}
```

I set age=7 but I got no exception or any message, it returns 7! why?

Comment: I guess manually invoking the setter method will hardly do any validation. You'll probably have to use the entire bean container managed.

Comment: @rethab That it is, usually bean validation is used as part of a JEE container and is the container which launches the validation.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera in this case you need a rather sophisticated setup with a container and somehow the setter would have to be triggered (you cannot trigger it yourself as that circumvents the validation). but even then, the more things you add to your environment to test it, the more it will differ from your productive setup which also means you can be less sure it works in practice. imao, java ee was not designed to be very test-friendly.